# Concat object with new values and transform it to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I have such case: I'm pushing to object new `key-value` pairs, like:

```
let a1 = {key1: 'val1'};
let a2 = {key2: 'val2'};
const result = {...a1, ...a2};
```

and as a result I get a valid new object: `{key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2'}`.

but there is a third case:

```
let a1 = {key1: 'val1'};
let a2 = {key2: 'val2'};
let b1 = {key1: 'val1b'};
const result = {...a1, ...a2, ...b1};
```

and as a result I should get:

```
{key1: ['val1', 'var1b'], key2: 'val2'}`.
```

so -> if there is already such a key -> transform this key values to array and push them.

I tried so:

*for... all of my objects to push:*

```
const keysToPush = Object.keys(b1);
const keysInitial = Object.keys(a1); // foreach too
if (keysInitial.includes(keysToPush)) // push as array
```

but it looks to ugly

probably there should be more elegant solution?

Comment: The elegant solution is writing a function to do what you say is the ugly part. Then you can call `addToObject(a1, b1);`

Comment: What if you have `b1 = {key1: 'val1'};`? Would you still want an array in that case?

Comment: @trincot - no, just one key:value part.

Comment: So, that means you don't want an array with duplicate values, only unique ones?

Comment: @trincot correct.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the key exists. If it does, check if it's an array, and handle each case accordingly:

```js
let a1 = {
  key1: 'val1'
};
let a2 = {
  key2: 'val2'
};
let b1 = {
  key1: 'val1b'
};

const merge = (...o) => {
  let res = o.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    Object.entries(curr).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      acc[k] = (acc[k] && Array.isArray(acc[k]) ? [...acc[k], v] : (acc[k] ? [acc[k], v] : v));
    });
    return acc;
  });
  return res;
};

let result = merge(a1, a2, b1);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the use of `Map` (for the keys) of `Set` (for the values per key), as the `Set` will ensure no duplicate values. At the end of the process the `Map` can be converted to a plain object, and the `Set` to either a single value or an array of values:

```js
// Sample input with some repetition:
const objects = [
    { key1: 'val1' },
    { key2: 'val2' },
    { key1: 'val1b' },
    { key2: 'val2' },
    { key1: 'val1b' }
];

const pairs = objects.flatMap(Object.entries);
const map = new Map(pairs.map(([k]) => [k, new Set]));
pairs.forEach(([k, v]) => map.get(k).add(v));
const result = Object.fromEntries(Array.from(map, ([k, set]) => 
   set.size < 2 ? [k, ...set] : [k, [...set]]
));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at each property and decide if to assign or convert to array and push the value.

```js
const
    migrate = (target, source) => {
        Object.keys(source).forEach(key => {
            if ([].concat(target[key] || []).includes(source[key])) return;
            if (key in target) {
                if (!Array.isArray(target[key])) target[key] = [target[key]];
                target[key].push(source[key]);
            } else {
                target[key] = source[key];
            }
        });
        return target;
    };

var a1 = { key1: 'val1' },
    a2 = { key2: 'val2' },
    b1 = { key1: 'val1b' },
    b2 = { key1: 'val1b' },
    result = [a1, a2, b1, b2].reduce(migrate, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to merge objects.The steps of solution are:

- Create a function which accepts any number of objects using rest parameters
- Create an empty object which will be result.
- Loop thorough all the objects using `forEach`. Inside `forEach` create a another nested `forEach` to loop through entries of object.
- Check if the key already exists in result obj.

  - Check if its values is an array then push new value to it.
  - If its not array just convert it to array of two values
- If the key doesnot exist that add it normally as key of object.

```js
function mergeObjs(...objs){
  const res = {};
  objs.forEach(x => {
    Object.entries(x).forEach(([k,v]) => {
      if(res[k]){
        if(Array.isArray(res[k])) res[k].push(v)
        else res[k] = [res[k],v]
      }
      else res[k] = v;
    })
  })
  return res;
}

let a1 = {key1: 'val1'};
let a2 = {key2: 'val2'};
let b1 = {key1: 'val1b'};

console.log(mergeObjs(a1,a2,b1))
```